# Show that the set of complex numbers is complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

I know that the set of complex number is a normed linear with norm $\|z\|=|z|$.
The induced metric is $d(z,w)=|z-w|$ for complex $z$ and $w$.
But I want to prove that the set is complete.Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete?

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Prove that a finite product of complete metric spaces is complete and use $\Bbb C\simeq\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Some more hints for future readers: $\simeq$ here means "isomorphic as metric spaces", i.e. there is an isometric bijection. The [product metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric) on $\Bbb R^2$ is [strongly equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence) to the Euclidean one.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Show that if $\langle x_n+iy_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb C$, then $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric. Then use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is complete.

Answer (score 4):

If $(z_n) = (x_n) + i (y_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$ then $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}.$ Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, $x_n\to x$ and $y_n \to y,$ so $z_n \to z = x+iy.$